# What happens if lua is interrupted by a signal?

Tags: c, lua, signals, posix

Lua docs say:

> The Lua library defines no global variables at all. It keeps all its state in the dynamic structure lua_State and a pointer to this
>   structure is passed as an argument to all functions inside Lua. This
>   implementation makes Lua reentrant and ready to be used in
>   multithreaded code.

But is it true? Has anyone tried to verify this? What if a signal is raised and caught by a custom handler during the execution of `lua`? That is, is `lua` itself (never mind the system calls it makes) truly reentrant?

EDIT:

A well-known problem in `lua` is the lack of a timer implementation. These can be implemented using `POSIX` timers, that raise a signal. But raising such a signal may interrupt the execution of `lua` itself. The canonical solution to solve this problem is the masking/unmasking of a signal, but if `lua` were truly re-entrant this would not be needed.

Comment: Why don't you believe the documentation? Signals are a whole other issue. As long as you call signal safe functions in the custom signal handlers, you should be good.

Comment: The docs talk about multithreading, a raised signal is something different. It may interrupt lua while it is executing, while a thread does not interrupt.

Comment: I also doubt, for example, that 2 threads using the same `L`, could call into `lua` at the same time, only if they were synchronized. The docs aren't really precise.

Comment: Signal handlers are very limited in what they can do. Setting a global flag is about it. The standalone Lua interpreter does that to interrupt Lua scripts cleanly.

Comment: @lhf if the code they call is reentrant, then they can call it, but apparently `lua` is not and that is what I wanted to know. It seemed too good to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT, re-entrancy is a single threaded concept, and somewhat independent from multi-threading. Multi-thread safety relates to data coherence when concurrent read/write shared data, whereas re-entrancy relates to state coherence of function pre/post signal, within one thread.

A function is either multi-thread safe, or it is not. There is no in-between. However, it is not so simple with regards to re-entrancy: there are conditions under which a function is re-entrant, and conditions under which it is not; for some functions, there are no conditions under which it is re-entrant. I'm not a computer scientist but my guess is that there are very few functions, if any, that would be re-entrant under all conditions. Like `void f() {}` would be one, but it's not very useful :)

The following are probably true:

1. A required condition for a function to be re-entrant is that it must not use any static or global data or data that can be set from outside itself (such as registers or DMA).
2. Another required condition for re-entrancy is that the function only call re-entrant functions. In this case the function is re-entrant with the sum of all conditions required for the called functions to be considered re-entrant. So if A calls B and C, and B is re-entrant if condition b is true, and C is re-entrant if condition c is true, then a necessary condition for A to be re-entrant is conditions b and c must be true.
3. A function that accepts at least one argument is only re-entrant if 1 and 2 are true and the signal handler does not call, directly or indirectly, the function with the same argument.
4. An API is re-entrant in the same manner as the totality of its functions. This means that there may be only a subset of the API that can be said to be re-entrant, under certain specific conditions (1-3), and other functions are not re-entrant. This does not mean the API is not re-entrant; just that a subset of it is re-entrant, under certain conditions.

If the above is correct, then you have to be more specific when asking (or stating) whether Lua is re-entrant, to ask which subset of Lua functions are known to be re-entrant, under what conditions. Apparently all Lua functions satisfy 1, but which ones satisfy 2? Almost all Lua API functions accept at least one argument, so under the condition that your signal handler does not call directly or indirectly the same Lua function with the same Lua state variable, you could say that Lua is re-entrant for those functions that don't call non-reentrant functions.

Update 1: why condition 3:

Consider

```
void f(const Foo& foo) {
   if (foo.bar) 
       do stuff 
   signal happens here, calling isr()
   modify fo
}

Foo* isrFoo; 

void g() {
   Foo foo; 
   isrFoo = & foo; 
   f(foo)
}

void isr() {
   f(*isrFoo)
}
```

Although `f(const Foo&)` does not use globals or static (although strictly speaking it doesn't know if `a` is a ref to such var), the object received can be shared by multiple objects and hence, in `isr()`, can be modified, such that when `f()` resumes, `foo` is no longer same as when interrupted. One could say that `f()` is re-entrant (in single-thread) but here `isr()` is interfering, making `f()` non-re-entrant in that particular case. Assuming that an object copy op could be made atomic, `f()` could be made re-entrant even for this particular design of `isr()` if `foo` was copied into a local variable of `f` before being used, or if `isr()` made a local copy, or `foo` was pass-by-value.

Update 2: russian roulette

Russian roulette is a game of chance. So no, re-entrancy is not game of chance: given the above, the manual says basically that if your signal handler does not call (directly or indirectly) Lua C API functions, then you can consider the Lua C API functions re-entrant because of the way the API was designed and implemented.

For example if you have a timer that ticks (signals) every 100 ms, but the handler just sets a flag to true for "do something ASAP", and your code loops endlessly, calling a Lua function (via lua_pcall) at every iteration, to check the flag, you shouldn't have any problems: if the Lua function is interrupted by the timer before the flag is checked, the flag will get set, then upon return from signal the flag will be seen as true and your function will take action as designed.

However, if you are not careful, your Lua function (not the C API that calls it) may not be re-entrant, thus causing lua_pcall to not be re-entrant when calling your Lua function. For example if your Lua function (called via lua_pcall) checks the flag in two places:

```
function checkTimerFlagSet()
    if flag then ... end
    ... do stuff ... 
    if flag then ... end
```

and the timer signal occurs between the two checks, then the flag could be seen as false before signal and true after, during the same function call, which could lead to inconsistent behavior of your Lua function. But this is merely rule #1 not being followed (no choice since your signal handler can only set global variable) by your function, not by the Lua C API: this "bad" (i.e. non-reentrant) design of your Lua function is what caused one of the Lua C API functions (lua_pcall) to no-longer be re-entrant. It is re-entrant otherwise.

Comment: Why is the rationale for condition 3?

Comment: @user1095108 No space in comment, will extend answer

Comment: This makes me think reentrancy is a kind of Russian roulette and we need to assume non-reentrancy. There is no way to know what function the signal is going to interrupt, except when masking a signal.

Comment: @user1095108 I wouldn't say so. I've added other update to explain.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that lua keeps all its variables in `lua_State`. If a signal occurs, that signal will be handled in `C`. You cannot call `lua` safely from your signal handler, just as you can't call even some thread safe functions from a signal handler.

What the documentation is saying is that if you have different threads with different `lua_State` variables, they can each safely run lua without the need to synchronise between them.

Comment: If what you say is true, then `lua` is not truly reentrant and the docs are wrong, period.